# Get the name of the reference that the extension method was called on

Tags: c#

Let's say I have and extension method called MyExtensionMethod.

I want to use it like this:

```
var x = new MyClass()
x.MyExtensionMethod()
```

Then, inside the extension method, I want to get the name of the reference that it was called on:

```
public static void MyExtensionMethod(this object param)
{
    //get the name "x" somehow
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: you want to get the actual variable name?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I want.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that. What is your situation that you need to do that?

Comment: The variable name in most cases is lost during compilation.

Comment: It sounds like there's a better approach, if you'd explain the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: I wanted to somehow simplify Guard.ArgumentNotNull(), because it was annoying that you always had to supply the argument name as string

Comment: If that were possible, what "reference name" would you expect to show up in a call such as `new MyClass().MyExtensionMethod();`?

Comment: Uhm.. null? But yeah, this seems truly a duplicate. Close it.

Comment: @KornélRegius It may have started as a duplicate, but I think you'll find that my answer below addresses your underlying problem (which you mentioned in a comment) exceedingly well.

Comment: Yes, the answer indeed goes far beyond the generic problem and solves my special one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, this is not possible. The information which is sure to be available is the following:

1. The name of the calling method.
2. The name of the file where the call occurs.
3. The line number of the call.

Source: [Caller Information (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx)

---

If you are just trying to simplify your argument checking, create a file in the following folder:

**%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets**

If you have multiple versions of Visual Studio, or a different version than 2012, an appropriately named alternative folder will exist for the other version(s).

Name the file **ThrowIfArgumentNull.snippet**, with the following content. To use it, type `tan` in the editor and press tab twice. You'll get IntelliSense support for typing the argument name, and the string argument will be filled in automatically. This snippet creates a standard `ArgumentNullException`, but you can modify it to use a `Guard` or `Argument` class if that's what your project uses.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>Throw if argument null</Title>
      <Author>Sam Harwell</Author>
      <Description>Throw an ArgumentNullException if the specified argument is null.</Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>tan</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>arg</ID>
          <ToolTip>arg</ToolTip>
          <Default>arg</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="false">
          <ID>ArgumentNullException</ID>
          <ToolTip>ArgumentNullException</ToolTip>
          <Default>ArgumentNullException</Default>
          <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.ArgumentNullException)</Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[if ($arg$ == null)
    throw new $ArgumentNullException$("$arg$");$end$]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: This is when I say "Everything went better than expected". I just tried simplifying my argument null checking, and instead I learnt how to define custom code snippets for Visual Studio. :)