# Making an add-in for intellisense of Visual Studio 2010 Premium

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in

Is it possible to make a add-in for IntelliSense so that you can for example type `if` then press enter or tab then IntelliSense "imports" that snippet?

If not is there any way, except for the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are attempting to add statement completion to a new language in Visual Studio, Microsoft has posted the following walkthrough to help with the process.

[Walkthrough: Displaying Statement Completion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success making my own snippets with [SnippetEditor](http://snippeteditor.codeplex.com/)

Comment: But can you use that for what I want to do? Cause I don't want to make my own snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the ability to add custom snippets. In [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22016175/138304) I give an example of creating and installing a snippet.

The specific item you are looking for regarding IntelliSense is the `Shortcut` element, which appears as the following line in the linked answer.

```
<Shortcut>tan</Shortcut>
```

Note that you probably will not be able to reuse the shortcut already used by another snippet.  By default, Visual Studio 2010 installs a snippet **if.snippet** in the following location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#

If you want to replace the snippet used for the shortcut `if`, you'll need to either edit this file, or remove it to use one installed in your user profile.

Comment: I don't want to add or make my own snippets. I just want to if I type `if` then InteliSense pops up and then I press <kbd>Enter</kb or Tab it inserts that and the body.